# Is CV the right site for this question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

I just asked the following question:

[What are attention mechanism exactly?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344508/what-are-attention-mechanism-exactly)

It seems that attention-related questions haven't received answers on this site. Is this the right site for these questions? After [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), I found another site which seems related to Deep Learning questions: [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) (and I hope there isn't a third one). I believe Cross Validated is the most suitable site for this kind of questions, but I would like to have your confirmation.

Comment: It seems to pertain to ANNs, which are on topic. I would say it's OK. We can see how it fares. In the interim, you added the `[attention]` tag, but it has no excerpt. Can you provide one?

Comment: Hi @gung, I didn't create the `[attention]` label, I just used it because the site auto-completion suggested it (I did notice that it didn't have an excerpt, which I found odd). Given that I've never really understood what attention mechanism are (that's why I'm asking), I don't feel qualified to write an excerpt. If no one else volunteers to write a proper excerpt, I can surely parrot back the sentences commonly used to describe attention, but I'm not sure I'll make the community a great service.

Comment: FWIW the tag was created by @FranckDernoncourt.

Comment: Sorry for not having written an excerpt when creating the tag :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's on-topic here because it is about machine learning, and machine learning is squarely on-topic here.

Comment: Some folks have said "it is too software-side of machine learning" so it goes on stack-overflow.  Some folks have said "its too pure-mathy" so it goes on mathematics or data science.  Some have said "its too academia" or "its too work-professionalism" so I had to move to those forums.  There is no perfect Venn diagram as to which parts of stack-exchange it goes on, but it can go on one of them.

Comment: @EngrStudent those folks are wrong. StackExchange does **not** have the philosophy "It's not offtopic *here* only because it's *better* suited elsewhere". If something is on-topic on both A and B, OP can decide where to post, but only pick one.

Comment: Try this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/186430  Since when isn't using a neural network to forecast time-series data on-topic?

Comment: @EngrStudent I'm not sure what you're asking. In this thread, DeltaIV asks about a specific question, and I say that DeltaIV's question is on-topic because it's about ML. You're asking about a different question, and saying that this second question is on-topic because it's about ANN time-series forecasting. This seems to be an entirely new question. Perhaps you would find more helpful answers if you opened your own meta thread.

Comment: I was just supplying one of several examples where just because something is "machine learning" or otherwise "core" to stats, it gets voted as "off-topic" for the stats forum.  Goes along with the first topic.  fwiw, I love your answer, and I want these sorts of things to be on-topic.  I've just been axed and seen things axed that depart from the ideal.

Comment: @EngrStudent Just speculating, but when the title includes "how to do ... in R," people tend to regard that as off-topic because the question asks for explanation of how to use software -- that is, the answer is code and/or software documentation. On the other hand, if the question asked for the predictive equations for a specific model, it would probably be on-topic -- the answer is about machine learning as a mathematical discipline, not software engineering.